# Driver and kernel module install for FPGS fails

Tags: opencl, fpga

I am trying to install [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) on a machine with the following specs:

- CentOS 6.8
- Kernel version 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64
- 4G of RAM
- FPGA board "Nallatech 395 – with Stratix V D8"

> **aocl version**

aocl 16.0.0.211 (Altera SDK for OpenCL, Version 16.0.0 Build 211, Copyright (C) 2016 Altera Corporation)

However, I receive error **[Q 2-3]** described in the following page:
http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=46355

> /#aocl install aocl install: Running install from
>   /root/altera/16.0/hld/board/nalla_pcie/linux64/libexec Using kernel
>   source files from  /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 make: ***
>   /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64: No such file or directory. 
>   Stop. cp: cannot stat `./aclpci_drv.ko': No such file or directory
>   FATAL: Module aclpci_drv not found.

The page above suggests to execute the following command:

> **yum install kernel-devel**

However I still receive the same error.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

I [found](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=50090&page=2) a thread with a similar error, the following solution *could* work for you. However, this solution is based on version 14.

> First navigate to the linux/driver of the BSP folder which for you should be located at ***root/altera/16.0/hld/board/nalla_pcie/linux64/driver***
>
> Find and edit the file ***aclpci.c***: At the top of the file add the following lines:

```
 #define __devinit
 #define __devexit
```

> Secondly edit ***aclpci_cmd.c***: On line 83 remove the assignment
>
> *Change*:

```
 result = pci_restore_state(aclpci->pci_dev);
```

> *to*:

```
 pci_restore_state(aclpci->pci_dev);
```

> On lines 438-440 comment out the following statements:

```
 if (dev->aer_firmware_first) { 
     return -EIO; 
 }
```

> You should now be able to run "aocl install" successfully.

Comment: I tried the above solution. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 though. It didn't work for me. Any other solution?